# Xcode doesn't show up in spotlight results, neither search results

Tags: finder, xcode, spotlight, search

I haven't noticed exactly when it happened but previously I was always using spotlight to run Xcode. Now if i'm typing "Xcode" in it, only folders containing this name show up, or some xcode projects, not all though. 
I've tried search in finder and even choosing kind of files - Application, still no luck.
Did Anybody face this problem before?

Comment: does it happen only with xcode?

Comment: it looks like only to xcode. other apps that i run through the spotlight (like Chrome, Pages, Terminal, TextWrangler, etc.) are working fine as it was before.

Comment: i think that has happened after some xcode update or so...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try [Rebuilding Spotlight index.](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/17/rebuild-spotlight-index/)  You can do it from the Terminal:

```
$ sudo mdutil -i on /
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it helped you, cheers! :-)

Comment: Just to let people know that this answer still works as of 2017.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Xcode 8.3. It simply stopped showing up in the spotlight search result. Rebuilding by adding Application folder to the privacy list in spotlight preferences, didn't help.

Executing `sudo touch /Applications/Xcode.app` in the Terminal worked.

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: For me only a combination of both steps worked, only touching Xcode didn't work, but after putting in into the privacy list and then running the command fixed the problem

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading from El Capitan to macOS Sierra I had the same problem.

The only command that did the trick was:

```
sudo mdutil -E # from mdutil usage "Erase and rebuild index"
```

If that one doesn't work directly, try running this command first:

```
sudo mdutil -i on # from mdutil usage "Turn indexing on or off"
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating the permissions did the trick for me: `chown -R $(whoami):staff /Applications/Xcode.app`

Suggested from here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82503

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review